# Configuration location for asp.net version of a website

Tags: asp.net, iis, version, aspnet-regiis.exe

after a crash I had to reinstall my windows server.

we have >1000 websites with combinations of asp.net versions on our machine  (1.1 , 2 , 4) .

I looked inside the IIS metabase for the version of asp.net version of the websites but it's not there.
Does anyone know where this data is stored ?

(it's a server crash so i cannot do aspnet_regiis -lk )

Thanks
avi

Comment: IIS V6 ( Windows 2003 Std)